# How does it sound to an English speaker if no articles are used?

Tags: articles

How does it sound to an English speaker if no articles are used?
How is it perceived? What do you feel when you are reading it?
What do you feel if adjectives used instead articles?
For example: not "the house is big" but "your house is big" or "this house is big"
In general. Without any specific context.
Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn’t it depend on what you are trying to say? In some cases, it would sound better, but it others, it might sound worse. P.S. Your profile says, “Just a programmer” – what would you change that to if you didn’t want to use an article?

Comment: In general. In my language the article stuff implemented by usage of adjectives without additional words like the an a. And it's very difficult to imagine what should make one to invent and use articles if everything is already there.

Comment: This question would likely be better-received if you included that information in the body of your question. With that knowledge, it makes more sense why you’re asking. You might want to do an edit. You might also appreciate knowing about [ell.se], if you’re not already familiar with that site.

Comment: Those aren't adjectives; *your* and *this* are determiners. If you use determiners instead of articles, it sounds fine. (In English, singular count nouns usually take exactly one determiner.) But if you say *house is big, but street is busy*, that sounds like you don't know how to speak English properly.

Comment: If you hear this "house is big" then you feel that it's just wrong? I see. Like: "it don't make any sense". Just don't know how to speak. Ok. Thanks a lot ! The problem is almost solved.

Comment: You can leave out occasional articles in speech, and I don't think anybody will notice. But if you leave them all out, it's probably going to sound like you're a foreigner who doesn't speak English very well. (Maybe like somebody speaking Russian who doesn't conjugate any verbs.) But we'd probably understand what you meant fine.

Comment: Just interesting: is it possible for a native English speaker to leave all articles out intentionally? Wouldn't it be very difficult to control yourself and leave them out all the time?

Comment: You noticed right my Slavic origin (just not Russian but Ukrainian). Interesting I just realized that if I don't conjugate verbs but just use the main part of the verb without the conjugating ending then it sounds pretty ok. Just like one swallows the endings of the words. It's felt like my mind adds those endings automatically and I can "hear" them. I tried this to other changeable features in my language and it worked well as well. A very interesting feeling. Just like they are useless.

Comment: Leave all articles out intentionally?  I tried it.  "Car goes too fast on street.  Ball rolls onto street.  Child follows.  Car stops just in time.  It was narrow escape!  I had big feeling of relief."  Yes, it sounds odd, and I would have to make an effort to talk this way, but everyone would understand.

Comment: A similar question has already been asked and answered on [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/129523/41273).

Comment: big, house is...

Comment: A question is unclear. A question has an incorrect premise. A girl has no name.